How to extract specific entities from unstructured text
Given a generic text sentence (in a specific context) how can I extract word/entities of interest belonging to a specific "category" using python and any NLP library?
For example given a step for a culinary recipe Add an onion to a bowl of carrots as input text, I'd like to retrive onion and carrots while given Sprinkle with paprika. should return paprika.
But this should also work with sentences like stir well, and cook an additional minute. that do not contain any food entity in them.
So far, what I was able to achieve is using the spacy library for training a NER module to parse sentences. The problem with the NER pipeline is that it is a rule-based parsing, it is trained providing a set of sentences and entities/matches/labels to learn, which works fine as expeted on sentences similar to the one used during train, but performs bad on new and different sentences:
nlp = spacy.load('trained_model')

document = nlp('Add flour, mustard, and salt')
[(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in document.ents]
# >> [('Add flour', 'FOOD'), ('mustard', 'FOOD'), ('salt', 'FOOD')]
# (quite) correct output

document = nlp('I took a building, car and squirrel on the weekend')
[(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in document.ents]
# >> [('building', 'FOOD'), ('car', 'FOOD'), ('squirrel', 'FOOD')]
# wrong output

document = nlp('stir well, and cook an additional minute.')
[(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in document.ents]
# >> [('stir well', 'FOOD'), ('cook', 'FOOD'), ('additional minute.', 'FOOD')]
# wrong output

I am aware that there are several similar questions and posts, but I have found only solutions working for "semi-structured" text, i.e. list of ingredients as 1 tsp. of sugar, 1 cup of milk, ... which can be easily solved using the previous rule-based approach. Also nltk and part-of-speech (POS) are an option, but I'd prefer an alternative solution rather than having to compare each noun with an exhaustive list of foods.
What instead I am looking for is a way of to extract specific entities or at least to classify words in generic text with additional categories beyond those of the basic parsing.
Which methods should I use/look at to achieve this?

Hello, interesting question, at the moment I don't have the answer but I can give some hints of where to look. In NLP there are techniques to compare words using word2vec. This creates a vector representation of words that allows algebraic operations such as comparing the similarity of words and phrases. Spacy already has this built-in, you can use the similarity function with the text to be evaluated and the list of words in your category (food). The food words should give a high similar value (close to 1), with that you can define a similarity threshold.

Named Entity Recognition (NER) is the right direction!
What you're observing is that your language model is not generalizing well/is overfitting to specific words.
2 possible approaches:

use rule based approaches as first prediction and combine it with a second model
use a transformer
based model and fine-tune it to your task. This requires that you have some training data (e.g. input: stir well, and cook an additional minute.; label: [O,O,O,O,O,O, B-COOK, I-COOK] if you want to label additional minute).


@camilo_chart I understand that similarity checks may be faster than strict equality checks, also in vector domain, but wouldn't this still fall under a "look up" solution? at this point wouldn't it be faster (and more precise) to use hashmaps and etc? (I appreciate your response anyway)

@polyte thanks for your comment, I will look at the resources you suggested and if necessary I will update/answer the question

@RiccardoRaffini yes, you are right. The embeddings produced by word2vec itself are not sufficient for NER. However, embeddings can be used as features for a classifier to predict the sequence of labels (e.g., B-COOK, I-COOK). Possible approaches for these classifiers are Support Vector Classification (SVC) or Conditional Random Fields (CRF). However, transformer-based approaches have largely replaced these algorithms in recent years.

Two different approach:
1. BERT NER
If you are low on resources, then consider trying BERT NER. Fine-tune it with your data. The thing with BERT NER is that under the hood, it uses an attention mechanism which allows it to get a good understanding of context. By using the context around the entities, it can learn which information to extract and which ones to ignore.
2. Small LLM
Apart from that, if you have ample resources, you can fine-tune a smaller LLM, such as LLaMA 1B, on your dataset. Even if you do not fine-tune it, I am sure you will easily achieve around 70% accuracy for extracting recipes given any sentences.
When training any model, make sure the data is balanced. This means you should not only include examples where entities are present, but also include sentences where there are no entities. This way, the model will learn to understand the difference between sentences that contain entities  and those that do not, helping it to accurately return no entities when none are present.
Example:
Sentences with Food Entities:

"Add an onion to a bowl of carrots."
"Sprinkle with paprika."

Sentences without Entities:

Stir well, and cook an additional minute.

Please pass me the book.

The cat sat on the mat.


By incorporating a different types of sentences, your fine tuned model will learn better.

Thank you for your answer, containing additional information. I am currently working following the transformers (BERT) finetuning path, a small test has already given me good results. Talking about data, I started to manually annotate a dataset of textual culinary instructions (tagging foods, tools and actions) as examples for training such models. As soon as I'm done, I'll update the question with the solution and upload the dataset.
